# Visual Studio for macOS Always Prompts to Enrol Mac under MDM

Tags: mdm, visual-studio-mac

I have Visual Studio Enterprise license issued by my Employer. I am using the MacBook Pro provided by them which is already enrolled for mobile device management with my email id by my employer with Microsoft Intunes Company Portal.

But every time I try to login to my account in VS, I get an error saying **Your login was successful but your admin requires your device to be managed by MyEmployer to access this resource.**

My device is already enrolled with MDM profile. I reported this issue as a service request in our IT support. But they have no idea of the actual error.

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong or need additional steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to Visual Studio for Mac 8.6 released on May 19, 2020 (today) fixed my issue. Their release notes state the following for Shell. Learn more at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2019-mac-relnotes#shell)

> **Shell**
>
> Visual Studio for Mac now has new identity libraries that should
>   ease many of the issues that users have faced signing in. In addition,
>   Visual Studio for Mac now supports device code authentication and
>   system browser. You can enable these two options in Preferences should
>   you need them. As a result of the new authentication flow, users who
>   have been signed in previously will need to re-authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your IT has configured Conditional Access incorrectly for Visual Studio. They should check the Conditional Access controls in Azure AD, and could also try unenrolling/reenrolling your device.

If IT can't resolve the issue, they should contact Microsoft Support who would be more helpful than StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll contact out IT support team again with above inputs